# Woocommerce Custom Order Action and Order Update WebHook problem

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i'm trying to solve this issue for weeks, have tried everything.
I have a Custom Order Action in my order admin panel like this:

```
function manage_actions( $actions ) {
   $actions['wc_my_custom_action'] = 'My Custom Action';
   return $actions;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_actions', 'manage_actions');

function custom_action_function( $order ) {
    update_post_meta( $order->id, 'Custom_Meta', 'Value' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_my_custom_action', 'custom_action_function' );
```

This works fine, if i open an order and then click on the 'My Custom Action' in the actions menu the 'Custom_Meta' key value pair is added to the order.

Now i have an Order Update WebHook (using API v3) set up and unfortunately it triggers before the 'custom_action_function' function runs so i always get the payload of the order without the new meta tag. I have tried everything i can to add the meta data prior to the webhook being fired, does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: What webhook? add the related details editing your question please.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec its called in WooCommerce "Order Update WebHook", its a pre-set WebHook that triggers when an order is updated (sort of because there are a lot of issues with it). The payload is the order data. What details would be useful to add to the question? Thanks